# How to read large number of XML files from file system

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

Lets assume, I have set of countries (more than 100). Each country can have many states. Each State will have one xml file in the file system. I have to search these xml files based on parameters like country,State or any Id which is present in the xml file.

xml file structure in the file system:

```
<Country code="in">
    <States Name="Delhi">
        <Subscriptions>
                <Subscription Id="100" Code="ABC">
                         ...
                        </Subscription>
                        <Subscription Id="101" Code="XYZ">
                         ...
                        </Subscription>
            </Subscriptions>
        </States>
</Country>
```

File structure (country folder -> State folder -> Subscription.xml file) :

```
US -> California-> Subscription.xml
US -> Alaska-> Subscription.xml
In -> Delhi -> Subscription.xml
In -> Tamil Nadu -> Subscription.xml
```

.
.
.

e.g: if a user search for id = 100, I have to look in each country folder... in each States folder...in each Subscription.xml file, if an id with 100 is present or not.

Please share your thoughts on this how to achieve search functionality on this using C#.

Comment: What have you done so far? For me this can only be achieved in one way, loop over all the files in all the folders and then extract the data you want from the files.

Comment: This might be a good use case for some database, perhaps a NoSQL one...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch or maybe even a MSSQL database, they work fairly well with EF and querying relational data.

Comment: As others say - you need to index that data in some way to be able to do fast searchs, you can use either SQL either noSQL (maybe even lucene) solution, question has not enough information to say which one is the best in your case.

Comment: Do you want to change the files or will the data be static? How many `Subscriptions` are you expecting for each `State`?

Comment: Once a approver approves the changes made by an user, xml file will get changed. There will be only one xml file for each state.

Comment: @Tomas: My initial guess, loop over files and put all data in a dictionary. Dictionary<Country,Dictionary<State, SUBSCRIPTION_XML_FILE_CONTENT>> and make the search on this dictionary. When the application starts, I should load this dictionary and put it in a cache. Please suggest if this will work or need anything more.

Comment: That would probably work, but as many people suggest you should use a database. Personally I would go for RavenDB or mongoDB since we are storing documents and RavenDB and mongoDB are document databases.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is not going to change, you could just load it all into an object graph in memory and implement the searching yourself. If there 100 countries each with 100 states each with 100 subscriptions that will only total 1000000 objects which shouldn't be too onerous.

If you want to support changes to the data then you are going to need a database of some kind.

If you want the search you perform to be flexible or if you might want to tweak the schema later I would suggest a database again.